# How do you list items that are both singular and plural

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

For example, would you say:

"There were carrots and gravy in the fridge."

You wouldn't say, "There were gravy." So does this make sense?

Another example:

"There are radio parts and a radio in the car."

You wouldn't say, "There are a radio in the car." So, again, how does this make sense?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: General rule is that the verb agrees with the closest noun.

Comment: There are eggs and an apple on the table, there is an apple and some eggs on the table.

Comment: There were butter and mayonnaise in the fridge. (Non-count nouns, but two *of* them.)

Comment: @BrianDonovan There was confusion and despair in the counting.

Comment: @livresque - Are there confusion and despair?

Comment: Here, *[**there is**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+beer+and+sandwiches%22) just beer and sandwiches*, but *over [**there are** beer and sandwiches.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22there+are+beer+and+sandwiches%22)